# C# - Writing strings to a stream using two bytes for length, not one

Tags: java, c#, string, sockets, utf-8

I am creating an easy to use server-client model with an extensible protocol, where the server is in Java and clients can be Java, C#, what-have-you.

I ran into this issue: Java data streams write strings [with a short designating the length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29), followed by the data.

C# lets me specify the encoding I want, [but it only reads one byte for the length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (actually, it says '7 bits at a time'...this is odd. This might be part of my problem?)

Here is my setup: The server sends a string to the client once it connects. It's a short string, so the first byte is 0 and the second byte is 9; the string is 9 bytes long.

```
//...
_socket.Connect(host, port);
var stream = new NetworkStream(_socket);
_in = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(_in.ReadString()); //outputs nothing
```

Reading a single byte before reading the string of course outputs the expected string. But, how can I set up my stream reader to read a string using two bytes as the length, not one? Do I need to subclass BinaryReader and override ReadString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# BinaryWriter/Reader behavior uses, if I recall correctly, the 8th bit to signify where the last byte of the count is. This allows for counts up to 127 to fit in a single byte while still allowing for actual count values much larger (i.e. up to 2^31-1); it's a bit like UTF8 in that respect.

For your own purposes, note that you are writing the whole protocol (presumably), so you have complete control over both ends. Both behaviors you describe, in C# and Java, are implemented by what are essentially *helper* classes in each language. There's nothing saying that you have to use them, and both languages offer a way to simply encode text directly into an array of bytes which you can send however you like.

If you do want to stick with the Java-based protocol, you can use `BitConverter` to convert between a `short` to a `byte[]` so that you can send and receive those two bytes explicitly. For example:

```
_in = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
byte[] header = _in.ReadBytes(2);
short count = BitConverter.ToInt16(header, 0);
byte[] data = _in.ReadBytes(count);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine(text); // outputs something
```

Comment: Yes, I do have full control over the protocol. Looking at this workaround, it seems the simplest option is to subclass the BinaryWriter/Reader classes for C#. Besides, I need to reverse the endianness anyways. Thank you for your time, Peter!